# Entries in an infinite series

Tags: limits

The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ such that its sum is bounded. Given that $a_n\geq 0$ for each $n$, can we prove that $a_n=0$ for infinitely many n?

Given that the sum is bounded, I think that each element must be very small. However, I am not sure if we can say that all $a_n=0$ after some large $n$.

Comment: Counter example : $a_n = (1/n^2)$ which is known to be a convergent series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not in general true.

Consider the series
$ \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac1{k^2} $.

Answer (score 3):

A *necessary* condition is that the **limit** of $a_n$ is $0$ as $n\to\infty$. It's not needed that the terms themselves are $0$ after some point. Because that would not be a series, but a finite sum.

Necessary means that it is not enough. There are series where $a_n\to 0$ but are not convergent, like $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, the harmonic series.

Consider the series
$$\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}+\ldots$$
The terms are never zero, nevertheless the series converges. The sum is $1$, by the way.

Hope this helps